# How do I use xsl:apply-templates on the node that is itself generated with xsl?

Tags: xslt, apply-templates

I have an xml like this:

```
<span reference="1">Reference Text 1</span>
<term reference="2">Reference Text 2</term>
```

And I need it to become this:

```
<span class="referenceText">Reference Text 1</span> <a href="1">[1]</a>
<i>Reference Text 2</i> <a href="2">[2]</a>
```

So, basically, if the element with the `reference` attribute is a span, we just leave it as is, adding `class="referenceText"`. If, however it is any other element, then we should also apply templates created for this element. That's why `<term>` should become `<i>` - I have a template for it:

```
<xsl:template match="term">
  <i><xsl:apply-templates select="@* |node()"/></i>
</xsl:template>
```

For the transformation of all elements with a `reference` attribute I have this template:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@reference]">

  <xsl:param name="href" select="./@reference"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="name() = 'span'">
      <span class="referenceText">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </span>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

  <xsl:text> </xsl:text><a href="#{$href}">[<xsl:value-of select="./@href"/>]</a>

</xsl:template>
```

Unfortunately, this results in the following output:

```
<span class="referenceText">Reference Text 1</span> <a href="1">[1]</a>
<term>Reference Text 2</term> <a href="2">[2]</a>
```

So, `<term>` is not converted into `<i>`. It looks like I need some sort of recursion to re-apply the templates to what's been generated, but I can't come up with anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using XSLT 1.0, you can capture the output in a variable and then use the [exslt:node-set](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/) function to apply templates to the variable. Try to avoid infinite recursion, though :)

```
<xsl:variable name="foo">
...
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($foo)"/>
```

---

*(**EDIT:** incorporating additional comments relevant to this answer)*

In order to use an EXSLT extension, the first step is to declare its namespace. The EXSLT project website recommends doing so on your `<xsl:stylesheet>` node:

> The first step to using the extensions described in EXSLT is to define the relevant namespace for the EXSLT module. You should declare the namespace on the xsl:stylesheet element in your stylesheet.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">
  //...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In addition, the `extension-element-prefixes` attribute can be used to prevent the extensions namespaces from being added to the resulting document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exslt">
  //...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you maybe show me how to do this on my code? I just tried it and doesn't seem to work. Almost all my resulting document disappears.

Comment: You need to add xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" to your root element (or elsewhere) to define the exslt namespace. Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: I'm using `libxslt`. Tried adding `xmlns:exslt="exslt.org/common"` to the root element, no luck.

Comment: Argh, URL should begin with "http://", the editor keeps eating the prefix. We're using libxslt too, it does support exslt.